# psexec not executing command once I pass in command line arguments

Tags: psexec

I have to run the following command remotely on another server, the arguments are prefixed with `!=`:

```
wdrspc.exe !=BATCHTEST1,LGTY_PLAN_01
```

This works (but the exe fails because I'm not passing in any arguments):

```
psexec \\kiklogiappsd "c:\Program Files (x86)\Logility\SPC8.0\wdrspc.exe"
```

This does not work (psexec says system cannot find the file specified):

```
psexec \\kiklogiappsd "c:\Program Files (x86)\Logility\SPC8.0\wdrspc.exe !=BATCHTEST1,LGTY_PLAN_01"
```

I'm stumped, is it the `!=` syntax throwing off psexec?

Answer (score 1):

The correct command line would be:

`psexec \\kiklogiappsd "c:\Program Files (x86)\Logility\SPC8.0\wdrspc.exe" !=BATCHTEST1,LGTY_PLAN_01`

The program arguments should not be in quotes with the program path, or they'll be interpreted as part of the program path. When you quote a space in a command line argument, that tells the shell that the space is *part of* the argument, rather than separating two arguments. That's why you quote anything in `C:\Program Files (x86)`. But you *want* an argument-separating space between the program path and its arguments.